# web.config - windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-config, windows-authentication

I have a website with windows authentication enabled. I am trying to restrict who can access the website by adding allowusers.

It is working fine if I am in allow users list.

If a user login correctly using correct credentials --> If he is not in the allow Users List-->He should see the -->NoAccess.aspx

If the User enters wrong credentials--> He should go to --->NoAccess.aspx

Right now If I am not in the allowUsers list-->website is asking me to log in again and again -->Not taking me to NoAccess.aspx Page.

How can I make it work?

```
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="Domain\Usr1,Domain\Usr2"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/NoAccess.aspx"  mode="RemoteOnly">
<error statusCode="404"
       redirect="NoAccess.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: More than likely, access control is being applied to NoAccess.aspx. You should set up a [`<location>` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and allow access to `*` for that page.

Comment: `<error statusCode="404"` means `404 Not Found` error

Comment: Hi Wgraham - I added  Location tag above the <system.web> that I have and it is still working the same way as before. Am I doing some thing wrong? Please see below.<location path="NoAccess.aspx">
    <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>